# pass jquery variable to php and use it

Tags: php, jquery

I have this form:

```
<form class="getCurPd" method="get">
     <input type="hidden" id="lastpid" name="lastpid" value="" />
</form>
```

With some javascript code I've given dynamic value for that input.And now need to use that value in php code. Here it is:

```
<?php
 $cur = '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#lastpid").val();})</script>';
 $_terms = wp_get_post_terms($cur, 'product_cat');
 foreach ($_terms as $_term) {
       echo '<a style="color:#333;" href='.get_term_link($_term).'>product cat link</a>'; 
}
?>
```

But $cur isn't defined think that javascript syntax is wrong. Please help me find it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to use this jQuery("#lastpid").val() value inside wordpress php function wp_get_post_terms().

Comment: You totally misunderstand the difference between client-side and server-side code. To achieve what you want you should `post` the value from your form to php controller and deal with posted value.

Comment: @user3090189 , Hi mam , jQuery is client side language , PHP is server side ! :) And please stop using WPress , it is ruining PHP Dev's life and salary since 2002 !! It has NO object oriented support , its base code is Mess.

Comment: If you need to use the value from the hidden field, you can just submit and then use the $_GET var in php

Comment: I know that, and want to know is there any way to do this - write jquery code or pass jquery variable to php?

Comment: This question needs to be reopened based on the comment I guess -> `I know that, and want to know is there any way to do this - write jquery code or pass jquery variable to php?`

Comment: I've changed my question's title is it enough, or ask a new question?